# What is the word for being attracted to a person's character?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sapiosexual means someone who is attracted to intelligence.
What would you call someone who is attracted to character?

For clarification, I see character differing from personality in the sense that character more closely refers to a person's moral compass, how they treat others, whether or not they are considerate to strangers, honest and respectful in daily transactions, trustworthy, etc.

If character means more to me than physical appearance, I would be referred to as a ________?

Comment: Related: [Is there a word that means "attracted to talent" in the way that sapiosexual means attracted to intellect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/499278/191178)

Comment: Soulmate seeking is the classic romantic notion and already orthogonal to sexual attraction.

Comment: Do you mean being sexually attracted to people who have positive character traits such as integrity, sympathy and morality or do you mean being attracted to people because their characters are appealing? This is not necessarily the same thing, it is fairly common for women to be attracted to 'bad boys' because they are exciting even though they display few of the characteristics listed above. These women are attracted to the character but the attractive traits are not really positive ones. There are, of course, men who are attracted to 'bad girls' in a similar way.

Comment: Sapiosexual means _sexually_ attracted to intelligence. Doubtless there is a non-sexual attraction (doctoral candidates wanting to work with a certain professor, ...).